# Unable to Run Amethyst Starter Template: 'VkError(ERROR_INCOMPATIBLE_DRIVER)'

Tags: ubuntu, rust, vulkan, amethyst

I'm trying to run an Amethyst project, however I keep coming across an error that prevents me from getting a window to open.

I have installed the dependencies mentioned in the official Amethyst GitHub page and am using the [2D starter template](https://github.com/amethyst/amethyst-starter-2d/tree/fd8bff9ea6184c806064df3978fe358d3c5666da). I did not make any alterations to the code in the repository when running the program.

The error report with BACKTRACE=1:

```
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 10.75s
     Running `target/debug/amethyst-starter-2d`
[INFO][winit::platform::platform::x11::window] Guessed window DPI factor: 1
[INFO][amethyst::app] Initializing Amethyst...
[INFO][amethyst::app] Version: 0.12.0
[INFO][amethyst::app] Platform: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
[INFO][amethyst::app] Amethyst git commit: 
[INFO][amethyst::app] Rustc version: 1.39.0-nightly Nightly
[INFO][amethyst::app] Rustc git commit: bdfd698f37184da42254a03ed466ab1f90e6fb6c
[WARN][gfx_backend_vulkan] Unable to find extension: VK_KHR_surface
[WARN][gfx_backend_vulkan] Unable to find extension: VK_KHR_xlib_surface
[WARN][gfx_backend_vulkan] Unable to find extension: VK_KHR_xcb_surface
[WARN][gfx_backend_vulkan] Unable to find extension: VK_KHR_wayland_surface
thread 'main' panicked at 'Unable to create Vulkan instance: VkError(ERROR_INCOMPATIBLE_DRIVER)', src/libcore/result.rs:1084:5
stack backtrace:
   0: backtrace::backtrace::libunwind::trace
             at /cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/backtrace-0.3.34/src/backtrace/libunwind.rs:88
   1: backtrace::backtrace::trace_unsynchronized
             at /cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/backtrace-0.3.34/src/backtrace/mod.rs:66
   2: std::sys_common::backtrace::_print
             at src/libstd/sys_common/backtrace.rs:47
   3: std::sys_common::backtrace::print
             at src/libstd/sys_common/backtrace.rs:36
   4: std::panicking::default_hook::{{closure}}
             at src/libstd/panicking.rs:200
   5: std::panicking::default_hook
             at src/libstd/panicking.rs:214
   6: std::panicking::rust_panic_with_hook
             at src/libstd/panicking.rs:477
   7: std::panicking::continue_panic_fmt
             at src/libstd/panicking.rs:384
   8: rust_begin_unwind
             at src/libstd/panicking.rs:311
   9: core::panicking::panic_fmt
             at src/libcore/panicking.rs:85
  10: core::result::unwrap_failed
             at src/libcore/result.rs:1084
  11: core::result::Result<T,E>::expect
             at /rustc/bdfd698f37184da42254a03ed466ab1f90e6fb6c/src/libcore/result.rs:879
  12: gfx_backend_vulkan::Instance::create
             at /home/ganidhu/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/gfx-backend-vulkan-0.2.3/src/lib.rs:375
  13: rendy_factory::factory::init
             at /home/ganidhu/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/rendy-factory-0.3.1/src/factory.rs:1032
  14: <amethyst_rendy::system::RenderingSystem<B,G> as shred::system::RunNow>::setup
             at /home/ganidhu/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/amethyst_rendy-0.2.0/src/system.rs:150
  15: shred::dispatch::dispatcher::Dispatcher::setup
             at /home/ganidhu/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/shred-0.7.2/src/dispatch/dispatcher.rs:25
  16: <amethyst::game_data::GameDataBuilder as amethyst::game_data::DataInit<amethyst::game_data::GameData>>::build
             at /home/ganidhu/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/amethyst-0.12.0/src/game_data.rs:300
  17: amethyst::app::ApplicationBuilder<S,T,E,X>::build
             at /home/ganidhu/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/amethyst-0.12.0/src/app.rs:882
  18: amethyst::app::CoreApplication<T,E,R>::new
             at /home/ganidhu/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/amethyst-0.12.0/src/app.rs:196
  19: amethyst_starter_2d::main
             at src/main.rs:33
  20: std::rt::lang_start::{{closure}}
             at /rustc/bdfd698f37184da42254a03ed466ab1f90e6fb6c/src/libstd/rt.rs:64
  21: std::rt::lang_start_internal::{{closure}}
             at src/libstd/rt.rs:49
  22: std::panicking::try::do_call
             at src/libstd/panicking.rs:296
  23: __rust_maybe_catch_panic
             at src/libpanic_unwind/lib.rs:80
  24: std::panicking::try
             at src/libstd/panicking.rs:275
  25: std::panic::catch_unwind
             at src/libstd/panic.rs:394
  26: std::rt::lang_start_internal
             at src/libstd/rt.rs:48
  27: std::rt::lang_start
             at /rustc/bdfd698f37184da42254a03ed466ab1f90e6fb6c/src/libstd/rt.rs:64
  28: main
  29: __libc_start_main
  30: _start
```

Comment: Same question on Reddit https://www.reddit.com/r/rust_gamedev/comments/csrymk/ubuntuamethyst_failing_to_run_amethyststarter2d/

Comment: I believe that this has nothing to do with Rust. Did you [install Vulkan](https://linuxconfig.org/install-and-test-vulkan-on-linux#h7-2-ubuntu) properly with all the required drivers? What does the `vulkaninfo` say? Do other Vulkan apps work properly on your system?